# How do I go about setting up BoneCP for use in Ibatis?

Tags: java, ibatis

I'm trying to setup iBatis to use boneCP for my JDBC. I haven't tried changing my code yet I'm just curious how I would need to go about doing it.

I haven't seen any good guides on how to setup iBatis with an external JDBC.

From what I have figured out:
The sqlConfig xml needs to be changed. The transactionManager type needs to be changed, and maybe something with properties.

Has anyone done this? or something similar with c3p0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoneCP provides a datasource, so tell ibatis to use it:

This may help:
http://derscheuch.wordpress.com/2008/06/06/how-to-use-a-datasource-with-ibatis-in-a-realm-within-a-tomcat-environment/

API for bonecp datasource:
http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/index.html